# select menu item reset to default fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a little problem with jquery in which I would like my dropdown option box to be reset to default value (the first group's name)

```
  <input id="leftv" name="n" type="radio" onclick="chooseLeft('val-');" />
                      <label for="leftv">left</label>
     <input id="rightv" name="n" type="radio" onclick="chooseRight('val-');" />
                      <label for="rightv">right</label>

<select id="val-left">
                          <option value="">Option Value</option>
                          <optgroup label="Main Value">
                            <option class="br" value="s">Main1</option>
                            <option class="br" value="o">Main2</option>
                          </optgroup>
                          <optgroup label="Sub value">

                <option class="br" value="v1">value1</option>                           
                <option class="br" value="v2">value2</option>
                          </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="val-right">
                          <option value="">Option Value</option>
                          <optgroup label="Main Value">
                            <option class="br" value="s">Main1</option>
                            <option class="br" value="o">Main2</option>
                          </optgroup>
                          <optgroup label="Sub value">

                <option class="br" value="v1">value1</option>                           
                <option class="br" value="v2">value2</option>
                          </optgroup>
</select>
```

and here is jquery code

```
function choose_Left(val){
            $('#' + val + '-left').attr("selected", false);
            $('.selected', 'div#' + left + '-valtable').removeClass('selected');
            $('#' + val + '-valtable span').text("Option Main");     
            $('#' + val + '-left').attr("selected", false);
            $('.selected', 'div#' + left + '-valtable').removeClass('selected');
            $('#' + val + '-valtable span').text("Option Value");
}
```

When I pick the first radio button I would like the second select dropdown to display Option Value which is the default one and this works as expected in all other browsers except IE9, which displays blank in the select of id=val-right. What can we do to make it right in IE9 ? :)

Here is what I have tried

```
$("select :first-child").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("selected", true);
});
```

But I could see any good outcome from that piece. :(

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a select in jQuery, the easily way is use the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

For example:

```
$('select.classname').val('the-value');
```

In your case, I think you can just use:

```
$('#val-left, #val-right').val('');
```